# Custom post metadata not appearing in public API

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, api, plugin-jetpack

I'm using wordpress.com's public REST API to retrieve custom posts from a Wordpress installation. The JSON that's being returned is missing all the custom fields, however. The fields are definitely there and working, because I can filter on them. For example this URL:

https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/swnfest.com/posts/?type=artist&meta_key=facebook&meta_value=outfitoutfitoutfit

is successfully limiting based on the `facebook` custom field, but that field isn't present in the response. Judging by the criteria for including custom fields in [this article](http://developer.wordpress.com/2013/04/26/custom-post-type-and-metadata-support-in-the-rest-api/):

> If the user performing the request is unauthenicated, he or she will
>   not be able to add, edit or delete any metadata; will be able to read
>   any metadata for which the key doesn’t begin with _ but will not be
>   able to read any metadata which begins with _ unless it is
>   whitelisted.

the field should be appearing. Is there something I'm missing, or is this a bug?

Comment: wordpress.com customizations are off topic here. Please ask their support.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance because I know nothing about Wordpress - but this isn't anything to do with wordpress.com (bar using their public API) - the site in question is a private wordpress installation. To my knowledge nothing has been customised, beyond the post type which is custom. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: Try making an authenticated request.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `rest_api_allowed_public_metadata` filter to whitelist the `facebook` custom field. It will then appear in the response:

```
add_filter( 'rest_api_allowed_public_metadata', 'jeherve_allow_fb_metadata' );
function jeherve_allow_fb_metadata() {
    // only run for REST API requests
    if ( ! defined( 'REST_API_REQUEST' ) || ! REST_API_REQUEST )
        return $allowed_meta_keys;

    $allowed_meta_keys[] = 'facebook';

    return $allowed_meta_keys;
}
```

Comment: Thanks; I have similar code in place but it doesn't make any difference. I raised this with Jetpack support and they think it's a problem on their end, so I'm waiting to see what happens with that.